# How to embed the Google Maps iPhone app within my own native iphone application?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

The Apple Developer Documentation explains that if you place a link in a [web page](http://www.verhoteles.com) and then click it whilst using Mobile Safari on the iPhone, the Google Maps application that is provided as standard with the iPhone will launch.

How can I launch the same Google Maps application with a specific address from within my own native iPhone application (i.e. not a web page through Mobile Safari) in the same way that tapping an address in Contacts launches the map?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 6.1.1 and lower, use the openURL method of UIApplication. It will perform the normal iPhone magical URL reinterpretation. so

```
[someUIApplication openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London"]]
```

should invoke the Google maps app.

From iOS 6, you'll be invoking Apple's own Maps app. For this, configure an MKMapItem object with the location you want to display, and then send it the openInMapsWithLaunchOptions message. To start at the current location, try:

```
[[MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation] openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
```

You'll need to be linked against MapKit for this (and it will prompt for location access, I believe).

You can also use

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London"]];
```

To open Google Maps at specific co-ordinates, try [this](http://www.carros.com.co) code:

```
NSString *latlong = @"-56.568545,1.256281";
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=%@",
[latlong stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

You can replace the latlong string with the current location from CoreLocation.

You can also specify the zoom level, using the (”z“) flag. Values are 1-19. Here's an example:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL         URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?z=8"]];
```

Comment: This code:

`code`for (int i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < result.length; j++) {
        if (result[i] > result[j]) {
            int temp = result[i];
            result[i] = result[j];
            result[j] = temp;
        }
    }
} `code`
Is not how Selection sort works. This is Bubble sort

Class Name

public class Main {
Would be better named as SelectionSort (or BubbleSort because that is technically what this is). [upmodels](http://www.upmodels.com) 
Your displayArray method lacks some braces. It is recommended to always use braces. Even for one-liners.